# Fit div inside cell to its content

Tags: css

I need to create a table like this:

```
| --------------------------------------------------|
| | Column A long |     |     | Column B |          |
| | Column A |          |     | Column B long |     |
| | Column A long |     |     | Column B |          |
| --------------------------------------------------|
```

The specific thing I need is that the text has to be wrapped by a colored rectangle that has to fit the content.
The only thing I have done until now is the following table:

[image]

But I need the colored rectangle to fit the text in it.
Any help with that?

Thanks

Comment: You're gonna have to be clearer as to what you mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, you simply need to declare `display: inline-block;` for the `<div>`s and be sure not to give them any explicit width:

```css
table, tr, td {
border: 1px solid rgb(227,227,227);
}

td {
min-width: 90px;
}

td div {
display: inline-block;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
padding: 4px;
border-radius: 8px;

}

tr td:nth-of-type(1) div {
background-color: rgb(22,163,47);
}

tr td:nth-of-type(4) div {
background-color: rgb(182,66,202);
}
```

```html
<table>

<tr>
<td><div>Column A long</div></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><div>Column B</div></tr>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div>Column A</div></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><div>Column B long</div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div>Column A long</div></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><div>Column B</div></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [float](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats) the items so that their width will be calculated using the [shrink-to-fit algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float).

Then, to prevent the items from stacking horizontally and force one per row, you can use [clearance](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#flow-control).

```css
ul {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul > li {
  float: left; /* Shrink-to-fit width */
  clear: left; /* One per line */
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #666;
  background: #B642CA;
}
ul:first-of-type > li {
  background: #16A32F;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Column A long</li>
  <li>Column A</li>
  <li>Column A long</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Column B</li>
  <li>Column B long</li>
  <li>Column B</li>
</ul>
```